# How to request div content from another site

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on making an chrome app that uses javascript to make download buttons.
I want the app to take the current page + append "/download" on it.
Then it would request HTML code from that link.

```
<div class="download-row">
<a href="http://www.website.com">A website</a>
</div>
```

It would take the href from the download page, then create buttons with the href on the original page.

---

OK I tried this on the website and I'm having syntax issues.

```
var links = ""
$('#right').load('www.mywebsite.com/download', function(data) {
data.find(".download-row a").each(function(){
    links += $(this).attr("href");

    });});
```

When I tested this in chrome's console, it printed out:

```
GET http://www.mywebsite.com/download 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught TypeError: Object <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
....
....
HTML data from the page.
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean to load data from another site and not a page on your own site?

Comment: another page on the same domain, sorry wasn't clear. the Jquery load isn't working properly tho.

Comment: If it's not working, you might need to try a relative path to the page you're trying to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/load/ to load data from other page. A sample example from jQuery documentation

`$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');`

There are many other demos available, try it. And if not use Ajax.

Comment: Op did mention loading content form another site, if that's the case, `load` won't work due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Yes!, it will have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, need to find another way